# TS2322: Type '_' is not assignable to type 'never'. angular

Tags: angular

im trying to use the websocket ( sockjs and stomp ) in my angular project to make a chat message, in my service.ts , whene i create the *addMessage* methode like this :

```
 public messages = [];
  addMessage(message: any, username: string, avatar: string) {
    this.messages.push({
      text: message,
      date: new Date(),
      user: {
        name: username,
        avatar:avatar
      }
    });
  }
```

the IDE shows those errors:

```
TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'. 
TS2322: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'never'.
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Related to the AddMessage Methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using interfaces:

```
interface IMessage {
    text: string;
    date: Date;
    user: IUser;
}

interface IUser {
    name: string;
    avatar: string;
}

public messages: IMessage[] = [];
addMessage(message: any, username: string, avatar: string) {
    this.messages.push({
        text: message,
        date: new Date(),
        user: {
            name: username,
            avatar:avatar
        }
    });
}
```